# Are rules questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

I think that we are going to get a lot of questions that ask about something in between a puzzle and a game, about the rules. I'm sure there are many rules questions that would be better fit for a games related StackExchange, but there will be some that apply specifically to puzzles. Do we want to answer these, migrate them, or [just close them as "RTFM!"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253473/2635662)?

Comment: See also [tag:rules].

Answer (score 2):

Questions about rule clarifications and judgements, and similar meta questions about the rules are unambiguously on-topic.

Questions asking for a complete set of rules are trickier. On the one hand, we don't want to just be a repository for the rules of all puzzles; on the other, not all puzzles are going to have clear Ms to RTF. I think we should err on the side of acceptance, and if it gets to be a problem we can revisit the issue then.